# How to Add Highlight to a High-Ploy SkinedMesh Object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am trying to add a glow effect to a Humanoid 3D Model in Unity 
and i am using this shader to reach my goal :
https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse

but this just make an outline with no Glow Effect.

How can i add a Highlight with Glow around the Models ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an object to glow in unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422692/how-to-make-an-object-to-glow-in-unity3d)

Comment: you also might have a look at [this **very cool** one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=56&v=SMLbbi8oaO8) in the links you can get to the github repository and just drag requireed files into your project (for the lazy ones)

Comment: thank you so much! @derHugo